# where col in() clause for geometry column in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, geometry

i have a table with geometry(point) column data type,
i stored data as POINT Object in mysql like this :

```
id      asText(latlng)

1   POINT(35.80684 51.427820000000004)

2   POINT(35.726940000000006 51.30407)

3   POINT(35.726940000000006 51.30407)

4   POINT(35.726940000000006 51.30407)

5   POINT(35.72343 51.303200000000004)

6   POINT(35.72675 51.303760000000004)
```

Now, i want to select and find some records by giving a list of POINTs and wants to use WHERE in() clause in sql syntax.

But this query is not working :

```
SELECT id, asText(latlng) FROM `points` WHERE latlng in (POINT(35.80684 51.427820000000004))
```

anybody can help me to resolve my problem?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT id, asText(latlng) FROM `points` WHERE asText(latlng) in ('POINT(35.80684 51.427820000000004)')
```

Comment: thanks, but does not return any records, i have changed the where clause to this `WHERE asText(latlng) in ('POINT(35.80684 51.427820000000004)')` and it works but is this query use spatial indexes for finding records?

Comment: No, that query does not use spatial indexes. That query requires a full table scan.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i leave a comment to your answer plz see that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The correct form of the query uses the [MBRWithin()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_mbrwithin) or [MBRContains()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_mbrcontains) geospatial functions in MySQL to actually compare the points and use a spatial index if available.

These functions can also compare dissimilar geospatial objects, to determine, for example, whether a point is within a linestring or polygon, using minimum bounding rectangles and R-trees.

```
SELECT id, asText(latlng)
  FROM points
 WHERE MBRWithin(latlng,POINT(35.80684, 51.427820000000004));
```

Live demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/394d0a/1

Comment: thanks, but i have multiple points & wants to find all in my table like this query `SELECT id, asText(latlng) FROM points WHERE asText(latlng) in ('POINT(35.80684 51.427820000000004)','POINT(35.72343 51.303200000000004)')` can you suggest me a query for multiple points with MBRWithin ?